# Exception Filter Attribute does not catch Exception(Web API 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I'm a newbie and developing a simple API project. I'm trying to catch an exception in my controller when my SQL server is offline.

As it can be seen I'm using dependency injection. If I don't use DI and access database simply by creating a context, I can catch the exception.

So basically I'm stuck.

**Controller:**

```
public class PlayersController : ApiController
{
    IRepositoryBase<Player> players;

    public PlayersController(IRepositoryBase<Player> players)
    {
        this.players = players;
    }

    [ApiException]
    //GET: /api/players
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {            
        var playerList = players.GetAll();                
        return Ok(playerList);                         
    }
```

**Api Exception Filter:**

```
public class ApiException : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        errorResponse.ReasonPhrase = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message;
        actionExecutedContext.Response = errorResponse;
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to see that it indeed doesn't run the code in `OnException`? Since I tried running the code you wrote(used a simple throw new Exception() in the Get() action to check) and it worked. Also you should name your Attribute classes with an Attribute postfix, that is `ApiExceptionAttribute`

Comment: Well, when I debug the program goes right past the filter.I have manually stopped the SQL server, put a breakpoint on "var playerList = players.GetAll(); "  ran the app and refreshed the page. But it just gives me a 500 internal server error. My aim is to get not implemented 501.

Comment: @M.Aroosi Could it be that it is because I'm using repository pattern?

Comment: Try putting breakpoints in the `OnException` method. Also, try stepping through the `GetAll` method to see that the exception is indeed thrown.

Comment: btw what is the internal server error you are getting(use your browser's network inspector)?

Comment: @M.Aroosi when I put breakpoint in the `OnException` method VS does nothing, just continues to execute. To expand on this; I put breakpoints in each class that has got something to do with the get request. What I found out is the problem starts at when PlayersRepository passes a context object to its BaseRepository class. At this point there are  different kinds of exceptions most of which talks about evaluation being timed out because of previous function not completing. So I'm assuming I have to do a connection check before I pass the context to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to provide a solution to my problem. Don't know if it's the proper way.

I re-designed my RepositoryBase constructor so that if database connection is closed it creates a context that is null.

**RepositoryBase:**

```
public RepositoryBase(DataContext _context)
    {
       if (_context.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
            this._context = null;
            this._dbSet = null;
       }
       else
       {
            this._context = _context;
            this._dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
       }
```

Then I updated GetAll() method so that if it sees a null context it will throw an exception.

**GetAll():**

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        if (_context==null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("DB Not Found");
        }                 
        return _dbSet;
    }
```

Then this exception is caught by ApiExceptionAttribute which ensures client recieves the exception code and the custom message I've thrown with it.